# Return optional value, depending on exception thrown by method used inside stream

Tags: java, exception, code-cleanup

Im trying to implement validation module used for handling events. The validation module is based on simple interface:

```
public interface Validator {    
    Optional<ValidationException> validate(Event event);
}
```

Existing code base in my team relies on the wrapping exception mechanism - I cannot really play with it.
I have encountered problems when implementing new validator, that is responsible for validating single event, in two terms.

Assume the event is `PlayWithDogEvent`, and it contains `Toys` a dog can play with.

Flow of validation of such event:

For each toy,

1. Check if its a ball
2. If its a ball, it should be not too large.

If any of the toys is either not a ball/too big ball, my `validate(Event event)` method should return `Optional.of(new ValidationException("some msg"))`.

I have implemented my validator the following way:

```
public class ValidBallsOnlyValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public Optional<ValidationException> validate(Event event) {        
        try {
            event.getToys().forEach(this::validateSingleToy);
            return Optional.empty();
        } catch (InvalidToyException ex) {
            return Optional.of(new ValidationException(ex.getMessage()));
        }       
    }
    
    private void validateSingleToy(Toy toy) {
        // In real code the optional here is kinda mandatory
        Optional<Toy> potentialBall = castToyToBall(toy);
        // Im using Java 8
        if(potentiallBall.isPresent()) {
            checkIfBallIsOfValidSize(potentialBall.get(), "exampleSize");
        } else {
            throw new InvalidToyException("The toy is not a ball!")
        }
    }
    
    private void checkIfBallIsOfValidSize(Toy toy, String size) {
        if(toyTooLarge(toy, size)) throw new InvalidToyException("The ball is too big!")
    }

}
```

The piece seems to work just fine, but im uncomfortable with the way it looks. My biggest concern is whether it is a good practice to place whole stream processing inside single try. Moreover, I don't think such mixing of exception-catching + returning optionals is elegant.

I could use some advice and/or best practices for such scenarios.

Comment: How do existing validators look like? You should strive for consistent code. Maybe ask your colleagues what the expected code style is for such validators?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> but im uncomfortable with the way it looks.

The API you're working against is crazy design. The approach to dealing with silly APIs is generally the same:

1. Try to fix it 'upstream': Make a pull request, talk to the team that made it, etc.
2. If and only if that option has been exhausted, then [A] write whatever ugly hackery you have to, to make it work, [B] restrict the ugliness to as small a snippet of code as you can; this may involve writing a wrapper that 'contains' the ugly, and finally [C] do not worry about code elegance within the restricted 'ugly is okay here' area.

The reason the API is bizarre is that it is both getting validation wrong, and not capitalizing on the benefits of their mistake (as in, if I'm wrong about their approach being wrong, then at least they aren't doing the best job at their approach).

Specifically, an exception *is* a return value, in the sense that it is a way to return from a method. Why isn't that interface:

```
public interface Validator {    
    void validate(Event event) throws ValidationException;
}
```

More generally, validation is not a 'there is at most one thing wrong' situation, and that goes towards your problem with 'it feels weird to write a try/catch around the whole thing'.

Multiple things can be wrong. There could be 5 toys, one of which is a ball but too large, and one of which is a squeaky toy. It is weird to report only one error (and presumably, an arbitrarily chosen one).

*If* you're going to go with the route of not throwing validation exceptions but returning validation issues, then the issues should presumably not be exceptions in the first place, but some other object, and, you should be working with a `List<ValidationIssue>` and *not* with an `Optional<ValidationIssue>`. You've gotten rid of an optional, which is always a win, and you now can handle multiple issues in one go. If the 'end point' that processes all this is fundamentally incapable of dealing with more than one problem at the time, that's okay: They can just treat that list as an effective optional, with `list.isEmpty()` serving as the 'all is well' indicator, and `list.get(0)` otherwise used to get the first problem (that being the only problem this one-error-at-a-time system can deal with).

This goes to code elegance, the only meaningful way to define that word 'elegance': It's code that is easier to test, easier to understand, and more flexible. It's more flexible: If later on the endpoint code that deals with validation errors is updated to be capable of dealing with more than one, you can now do that without touching the code that makes validation issue objects.

Thus, rewrite it all. Either:

1. Make the API design such that the point is to *THROW* that exception, not to shove it into an optional, -or-
2. Make the API list-based, also get rid of optional (yay!) and probably don't work with a validation issue object that `extends SomeException`. If you're not gonna throw it, don't make it a throwable.

If that's not okay, mostly just don't worry about elegance so much - elegance is *off the table* once you're forced to work with badly designed APIs.

However, there's of course almost always some style notes to provide for any code.

> `return Optional.of(new ValidationException(ex.getMessage()));`

Ordinarily, this is extremely bad exception handling and your linter tool SHOULD be flagging this down as unacceptable. If wrapping exceptions, you want the cause to remain to preserve both the stack trace and any exception-type-specific information. You're getting rid of all that by ignoring everything about `ex`, except for its message. Ordinarily, this should be `new ValidationException("Some string that adds appropriate context", ex)` - thus preserving the chain. If there is no context to add / it is hard to imagine what this might be, then you shouldn't be wrapping at all, and instead throwing the original exception onwards.

However, given that exceptions are being abused here, perhaps this code is okay - this again goes to the central point: Once you're committed to working with a badly designed API, rules of thumb on proper code style go right out the window.

> ```
> private void checkIfBallIsOfValidSize(Toy toy, String size) {
>        if(toyTooLarge(toy, size)) throw new InvalidToyException("The ball is too big!")
> }
> ```

Yes, this is a good idea - whilst the API expects you not to throw exceptions but to wrap them in optionals, that part is bad, and you should usually not perpetuate a mistake even if that means your code starts differing in style.

> `event.getToys().forEach(this::validateSingleToy);`

Generally speaking, using the `forEach` method directly, or `.stream().forEach()`, is a code smell. forEach should be used in only two cases:

- It's the terminal on a bunch of stream ops (`.stream().filter().flatMap().map()....forEach` - that'd be fine).
- You already have a `Consumer<T>` object and want it to run for each element in a list.

You have neither. This code is best written as:

```
for (var toy : event.getToys()) validateSingleToy(toy);
```

Lambdas have 3 downsides (which turn into upsides if using lambdas as they were fully intended, namely as code that may run in some different context):

- Not control flow transparent.
- Not mutable local var transparent.
- Not checked exception type transparent.

3 things you lose, and you gain nothing in return. When there are 2 equally succint and clear ways to do the same thing, but one of the two is applicable in a strict superset of scenarios, *always* write it in the superset style, because code consistency is a worthwhile goal, and that leads to more consistency (it's worthwhile in that it reduces style friction and lowers learning curves).

That rule applies here.

Comment: that's an excellent and in depth analysis of my scenario. It gets even more valuable for a junior developer, that works in some ugly, existing codebase. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Returning exceptions instead of returning them is weird, but whatever. (Why not return a `ValidationResult` object instead? Exceptions are usually intended to be thrown and caught).

But you could change your private methods to also return `Optional` instances which would make it easier to combine them. It would also avoid mixing throwing and returning and streams. Not sure if that is what you are looking for?

```
public class ValidBallsOnlyValidator implements Validator {

    @Override
    public Optional<ValidationException> validate(Event event) 
        return event.getToys()
                .stream()
                .filter(Optional::isPresent)
                .findFirst()
                .map(ex -> new ValidationException(ex.getMessage()));
    }
    
    private Optional<InvalidToyException> validateSingleToy(Toy toy) {
        // In real code the optional here is kinda mandatory
        Optional<Toy> potentialBall = castToyToBall(toy);
        if(potentiallBall.isPresent()) {
            return checkIfBallIsOfValidSize(potentialBall.get(), "exampleSize");
        } else {
            return Optional.of(new InvalidToyException("The toy is not a ball!"));
        }
    }
    
    private Optional<InvalidToyException> checkIfBallIsOfValidSize(Toy toy, String size) {
        if(toyTooLarge(toy, size)) return Optional.of(new InvalidToyException("The ball is too big!"));
        return Optional.empty();
    }

}
```

Comment: Sure, that will do the trick, but I think that I'll go with the List approach(or at least i'll try to convince my colleagues), consisting of some ValidationIssue objects, as both You and @rzwitserloot mentioned.